# No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp] in the implicit scope

Tags: json, scala

I am completely new to scala and play.api.libs.json.Format.

Here is my code, I don't know where I am doing wrong.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import shapeless._
import slickless._
import play.api.libs.json._


case class AnnotationDto(
                          sequence: Int,
                          tagName: String,
                          value: String,
                        ) {
  require(!tagName.isEmpty, "annotation tagName must not be empty")
}

case class CommentDto(
                       commentText: String,
                     ) {
  require(!commentText.isEmpty, "commentText must not be empty")
}

case class LoanConditionDto(
                             conditionGuid: String,
                             sourceSystemId: String,
                             sourceType: String,
                             name: String,
                             descriptionTemplate: String,
                             description: String,
                             status: String,
                             priorTo: String,
                             owner: String,
                             category: String,
                             borrowerFacingName: Option[String] = None,
                             borrowerFacingDescriptionTemplate: Option[String] = None,
                             borrowerFacingDescription: Option[String] = None,
                             encompassGuid: Option[String] = None,
                             conditionStatusDateTime: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None,
                             ignoreRecoveryFlag: Option[Boolean] = Some(false),
                             annotations: Option[List[AnnotationDto]] = None,
                             comments: Option[List[CommentDto]] = None,
                           ) {
  require(!conditionGuid.trim.isEmpty, "conditionGuid must not be empty")
  require(!sourceType.trim.isEmpty, "condition sourceType must not be empty")
  require(!name.trim.isEmpty, "condition name must not be empty")
  require(!description.trim.isEmpty, "condition description must not be empty")
  require(!status.trim.isEmpty, "condition status must not be empty")
  require(!priorTo.trim.isEmpty, "condition priorTo must not be empty")
  require(!owner.trim.isEmpty, "condition owner must not be empty")
  require(!category.trim.isEmpty, "condition category must not be empty")
}

case class LoanConditionUpdateDto (
  conditionGuid: String,
  encompassGuid: Option[String] = None,
  conditionStatusDateTime: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None,
  ignoreRecoveryFlag: Option[Boolean] = Some(false),
) {
    require(!conditionGuid.trim.isEmpty, "conditionGuid must not be empty")

}

case class LoanConditionsDto(loanNumber: Option[String] = None, conditions: List[LoanConditionDto], userId: String)

case class LoanConditionsUpdateDto(loanNumber: Option[String] = None, conditions: List[LoanConditionUpdateDto], userId: String)

object AnnotationDto {

  implicit val annotationFormat = Json.format[AnnotationDto]
}

object CommentDto {
  implicit val commentFormat = Json.format[CommentDto]
}

object LoanConditionDto {

  implicit val loanConditionFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionDto]
}

object LoanConditionUpdateDto {
  implicit val loanConditionUpdateFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionUpdateDto]
}

object LoanConditionsDto {
  implicit val loanConditionsFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionsDto]
}

object LoanConditionsUpdateDto {
  implicit val loanConditionsUpdateFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionsUpdateDto]
}
```

I'm trying to serialize an item object into a JSON String. I receive the error a this place

```
object LoanConditionDto {

  implicit val loanConditionFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionDto]
}
```

Error:

```
No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available  for scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp] in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
```

Can anyone please help me to fix the error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt that serialization a jdbc date was a good idea. If you want to anyway, you will have to provide a format for, as indicated in the documentation.

Comment: @cchantep can you please provide any sample code. To resolve above issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly was suggested in comment section you need to define `Format` or `Writes` and `Reads` for JSON for `java.sql.Timestamp`, for instance render it as long value representing unix time.
You can do it like:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import java.sql.Timestamp
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object LoanConditionDto {
  implicit val timestampReads: Reads[Timestamp] = {
      implicitly[Reads[Long]].map(new Timestamp(_))
  }

  implicit val timestampWrites: Writes[Timestamp] = {
    implicitly[Writes[Long]].contramap(_.getTime)
  }

  implicit val loanConditionFormat = Json.format[LoanConditionDto]
}
```

Scatie working example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Ko07Oa8iScW0i4vzE76K7w